# automapper: Export all automapper mappings from a DLL(where all mappings have been created) using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, mapping, automapper

I have DLL which contains all automapper mappings. Now i want these mappings into a an excel file which contains all mapping details like Source class, Source property, Destination class and Destination property. How we can achieve this using reflection or any other ways?

Comment: Can you not simply loop through the configuration object and print the mappings manually? It doesn't look like there is a built-in way to do this.

Comment: But that configuration should be loaded with the mappings? I only have one DLL file which contains the mappings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use Mapper.Configuation.GetAllTypeMaps(), and each TypeMap has the source/destination type.

Comment: If a property is of type of a class, Then the source propertyMap.SourceMember becomes null